# Using Boost/odeint with class (calling integrate from outside the class with ODE-function inside the class)

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

I have written a lot of code that got VERY messy over the last couple of weeks/months and I wanted to clean up, by putting most of it into classes. However, I can't figure out, how to call an ODE-function, that is *inside* a class with Boost/integrate from *outside* the class. I'm not sure, if this is the cleanest/best practise, but I tried something like this:

```
class ODEclass
{
public:
    // Lots of stuff here (initialization, methods, properties, parameters)
    void odefun(std::vector<double> x, std::vector<double>& dxdt, const double t)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And then calling somewhere outside the class:

```
integrate_adaptive(make_controlled<runge_kutta_cash_karp54<std::vector<double>>>(errTol[0], errTol[1]), odefun, Data, 0.0, something, something);
```

With `odefun` as `ODEclass::odefun`, `ODEinstance.odefun`, `ODEinstance->odefun` and every other way I could think of, but nothing works. Putting a `void odefun(...)` outside the class works perfectly fine, but that would go against my current cleaning urge.

I found answers here on Stackoverflow that would use `std::bind`, but those do odeint-calls form *inside* that class and don't seem to work in my case.

So how can I pass an ODE-function to odeint that is inside a class? Or is there a better (clean) way to do this? I hope, I put all the necessary information in here. If something is missing, please let me know.

Comment: What's missing is a self-contained minimal example of what you're trying to do. `atan` , `something`, `something` simply don't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a non-static member function requires an instance of the class.

The simplest fix is to mark the `odefun` as `static`. This will work unless you wanted to access the internals. Assuming that the correct signature for `odefun` is actually `void(std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>&, const double)` or compatible:

```
ODEclass instance;
auto odefun = std::bind(&ODEclass::odefun, &instance, _1, _2, _3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that's why I wrote `ODEinstance.odefun` and  `ODEinstance->odefun` below the code - this didn't work either. I now moved the call to `odeint` inside the class, then this approach works...

Comment: That makes zero sense. This code can absolutely work regardless of what object instance is bound. But, **do** show the code working code (*exactly*) so I can just show the equivalent. Code speaks authoritatively, and the compiler can confirm it.

Comment: I really don't know, what to show you. The code is REALLY long and I don't want to invest the time shortening it to a working minimalistic version. Maybe I had some mistake in my first attempt, but that version no longer exists. Basically I just moved `integrate_adaptive(make_controlled<runge_kutta_cash_karp54<std::vector<double>>>(errTol[0], errTol[1]), odefun, Data, 0.0, tFinal, tStep);` into a function inside the class (with `odefun` being `&ODEclass::odefun`). Might be, that I used `this`, `&this` or `*this` instead of `&instance`...

Comment: That obviously can never work outside the class, since `this` is a language keyword referring to the current class instance. But the point is, you can bind to any instance, as my answer shows exactly how to. You can even bind to a pointer or by reference: `bind(..., std::ref(instance), ...)`

Comment: Like I said - I *might* have used `this`. I don't remember... ;-) I already used a function pointer, which makes life a lot easier in this case. Can you give me an explanation why simply using something like `instance.odefun` as the function in `integrate_adaptive` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes. `instance.odefun` is not valid C++ syntax. C++ doesn't have something like closures or C#'s method groups - at the language level. So you have to state your intentions. A second aspect that you might be missing is that non-static member functions have the implicit `this` parameter, which means that their signature is fundamentally different between foo and bar here: `struct X { void foo(); static void bar(); }; void global_bar();` (but `global_bar` has the same signature as `X::bar`)